# Undefined index error but works when I use $_REQUEST

Tags: php, indexing, notice

I am new to PHP. I am trying to make simple user login form. Here's my code for `loginpage.php`

```
<html>
<form action="login.php" action="POST">
username<input type='text' name="username"><br>
password<input type='password' name="pass"><br>
<input type='submit' name='login'>


</form>
</html>
```

Now the other page is `login.php`

```
<?php 
    $username= $_POST["username"];
?>
```

And it gives me the error Notice: Undefined index: username in `H:\xampp\htdocs\login.php` on line 2

Answer (score 2):

Change--

```
<form action="login.php" action="POST">
```

TO

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

Change this

```
<form action="login.php" action="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
```

And try this

```
if(isset($_POST["username"])){

     $username= $_POST["username"];

 }
```

Comment: You have two problems here. 1. His submit button is named `login` not `submit` and 2. You shouldn't determine if a form is submitted based on the presence of the submit button value because some browsers (namely IE) don't send the submit button value as `$_POST` data if the user pressed the enter key to submit. Use `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']=='POST'` or `isset()` on the username and password.

Answer (score 1):

change this line

from

```
<form action="login.php" action="POST">
```

to

```
<form action="login.php" method="POST">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use php isset() function like

```
if(isset($_POST['username']))
{
  $username=$_POST['username'];
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<form action="login.php" **action**="POST">

<form action="login.php" **method**="POST">
```

Answer (score 0):

You should set:

`method="POST"`

and not

`action="POST"`

If you don't set it, it uses the `GET` method. You can access it with `$_REQUEST` as it has access to both `POST` and `GET` variable.